# Загрузка фото на сайт и его обработка

Tags: javascript, html, css, photo

Как на сайте реализовать загрузку фото пользователем с помощью тега button и отображения этой картинки. Все средствами HTML, CSS, JS, без сторонних библиотек или фреймворков.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const btn = document.querySelector('#add');  //ваша кнопка
btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
  const finput = document.createElement('input');
  finput.type = 'file';
  finput.onchange = (event)=>{
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(finput.files[0]);
    const img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = url;
    document.body.appendChild(img); //добавляем в конец body
    
  }
  finput.click();
});
```